# How to get the last occurrance of a specific month in the past with Carbon?

Tags: php, php-carbon

I'm looking for a simple, neat way to get a timestamp with [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) of the last occurance of a specific month in the past. Currently I'm doing it like so, but I think that has to be a more fluent way:

```
if(date('m') >= 8) {
   $lastAugust = new Carbon('first day of august');
} else {
   $lastAugust = new Carbon('first day of august last year');
}
```

Anyone ideas?

Comment: This is probably as good as it gets, PHP doesn't really have a language to express relative period contextually dependent on current period.

Comment: Have you tried `last august`?

Comment: `last month` works, but `last [month name]` doesn't.